# Access PHP array objects

Tags: php

I have the following array output:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => asdasd [email] => asdasdasd@asd.asd [message] => asdasd ) )
```

Which is given by the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['emailContent'])){
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $emailContent = $_POST['emailContent'];
        $emailContent = json_decode($emailContent);

        print_r($emailContent);
    }
```

I need to access the actual object and get the info from `name`, `email` and `message`.

How can I do this?

I have tried

```
$name = $emailContent[name];
$name = $emailContent['name'];
```

but no luck so far. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: try `$emailContent[0]->name`

Comment: tried `$emailContent.name;` or `$emailContent->name;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
$name = $emailContent[0]->name;
$email = $emailContent[0]->email;
$message = $emailContent[0]->message;
```

Comment: This does it. Not sure how this happened.. I've never worked with arrays like this before. Is it because I used JSON_DECODE?

Comment: @codeninja: if you need array from [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), use second parameter. like `json_decode($emailContent, true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Object array has a value on 0th index so you need to access it by specifying index as ,
`$emailContent[0]->name;` to get name value here 0 is index . Similar for email and message as ,
`$emailContent[0]->email;
$emailContent[0]->message;`

Answer (score 0):

if the array you have var_dumped is $emailContent you can retrieve the data as below :-

```
$emailContent[0]->name
$emailContent[0]->email
$emailContent[0]->message
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$name = $emailContent[0]->name;
$email = $emailContent[0]->email;
$message = $emailContent[0]->message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach( $emailContent as $index => $content )
    $name = $content[$index]->name;
    $email = $content[$index]->email; 
    echo 'Name: ' . $name .' | email: ' . $email.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: It'd be `->` not `[]` for proceeding properties of the object. (*`$emailContent[0]->name`...etc*)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the object from the array first and then use -> to access the name.

Try this `$name = $emailContent[0]->name;`